# Initial talking or initial talk?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I just saw "initial talking" as the title to the introduction on an academic text. I had only seen "talk" not "talking". Is initial talking also used as an introduction of sorts?

Comment: 'Initial talking' seems really odd in that context.

Comment: No. I'd give whoever wrote that a good talking to.

Comment: Please provide context.  Link or copy the text of the original use.  (Is "initial talking" the full title?  It is not uncommon to hear "initial talking points"...)

Answer (score 0):

It would be appropriate to use **talking** (and not **talk**)when meant to use as an adjective, eg;

> The initial **Talking** Circle was convened as a national one.

Use **talk** (however you could also use **talking** which would be awkward sounding) when meant as a topic, eg;

> An initial **talk** with the parents offered no information that could
>   help explain the boy's behaviour. (copied)
>
> An initial **talking** to the parents offered no information that could
>   help explain the boy's behaviour. (edited)

Answer (score 0):

As a noun, a "talk" is a more or less formal event in which one person talks at others. It may be like a lecture, or a presentation, or a parent telling their child something.

On the other hand "talking" (gerund or noun) is more closely formed from the verb. As a full noun it is unusual, but as gerund you might say "Talking to you was fun" It could have any of the meanings of the verb, but their it suggests "chatting".

In your context it is odd. Possible it is used to mean "Initial discussion", or I suppose it could summarise ideas raised in a discussion group or similar.  I would not use this expression in this context.